# How to fix 'ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Alright, I know how group by's work but this I keep getting this message and I have no idea what I did wrong.

What I should do is: Give the name and number of presidents of the party that has had the largest number of presidents.

```
select p1.party, count(p1.pres_name)
from president p1
group by p1.party, p1.pres_name
having 
   count(p1.pres_name) =
(select max(count(p2.pres_name))from president p2 where p1.part = p2.party)
```

Comment: many wrong in this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select party, num_presidents
from (select p.party, count(*) as num_presidents,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from president p
      group by p.party,
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use column name in aggregate function and in group by at the same time?
Try this:

```
SELECT PARTY,CNT FROM(
SELECT PARTY,COUNT(PRES_NAME) AS CNT
FROM PRESIDENT 
GROUP BY PARTY
ORDER BY 2 DESC
)
ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it without subqueries

```
select p1.party, count(p1.pres_name) cnt
from president p1
group by p1.party
order by count(p1.pres_name) desc
fetch first 1 row only
```